# Simplifying a numerical integral involving a variable integration limit

Tags: numerical-integration, function-construction, simplifying-expressions

I have a one-variable function basically consisting of an integral whose limits depend on the variable —I mean, something like this:

$F(x)=\int_0^{L(x)}{f(x,t)}dt$

with

$L(x)=5x$   and   $f(x,t)=t+x^2$,

for instance (actually, the expressions for $L$ and $f$ are much bigger and more complex).

So, what I want is to define such a function in Mathematica, as a single independent function that doesn't call or refer to any other function.

I tried something like this:

```
integrand[t_, x_] = t + x^2
limit[x_] = 5*x
myfunc[x_] = NIntegrate[integrand[t, x], {t, 0, limit[x]}]
```

and I get this:

> Out[108]= t + x^2
>
> Out[109]= 5 x
>
> During evaluation of In[108]:= NIntegrate::nlim: t = 5. x is not a valid limit of integration.
>
> During evaluation of In[108]:= NIntegrate::nlim: t = 5. x is not a valid limit of integration.
>
> Out[110]= NIntegrate[integrand[t, x], {t, 0, limit[x]}]

while I was expecting something like

> NIntegrate[t + x^2, {t, 0, 5*x}]

instead. Is it too much asking? What am I missing?

---

EDIT:

In case it was not clear enough, I was just looking for a way to create a new function (`myfunc`) out from other previous expressions (`integrand` and `limit`), in such a way that everything is contained by the new function (I mean, without references to other functions).

Comment: ```integrand[t_, x_] := t + x^2; limit[x_] := 5*x; myfunc[x_] := NIntegrate[integrand[t, x], {t, 0, limit[x]}];```

Comment: @flinty This is not what I am asking. If I do that, and then I write `myfunc[x]`, I do not get `NIntegrate[t + x^2, {t, 0, 5*x}]` (what I want) but `NIntegrate[integrand[t, x], {t, 0, limit[x]}]`.

Comment: What you are asking for won't work because `NIntegrate` must take numerical limits.  You must `Hold` it somehow then: `integrand[t_, x_] = t + x^2;
limit[x_] = 5*x;
myfunc[x_] := HoldFirst[NIntegrate[integrand[t, x], Evaluate@{t, 0, limit[x]}]]`

Comment: @flinty:  The `HoldFirst` doesn't seem to be necessary.  The code runs fine without it on my machine, and if it's there the output is (for example) `myfunc[1]` = `HoldFirst[17.5]`.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert yeah it runs fine for numbers, but try with a symbol e.g `myfunc[x]` - you will get a message `NIntegrate::nlim: t = 5. x is not a valid limit of integration.` - which is why you need the `HoldFirst` - adding it returns `HoldFirst[NIntegrate[integrand[t, x], {t, 0, 5 x}]]` instead, which has the `5 x` in the limit and is closer to what OP wants.